# For ConceptMapper: How do I include an ampersand in the canonical attribute? Or do I need to expand it to a word equivalent?

Tags: uima

I need to have entries like this:

`token canonical="Dow Jones & Company, Inc." POS="NNP" SemClass="property">/token>`

in my dictionary.

I tried:

`token canonical="Dow Jones (&)amp; Company, Inc." POS="NNP" SemClass="property">/token>`

without the parentheses, but I get the standard "The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference." as if it does not recognize the "amp;"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the special characters I needed to a list of StopWords. Works well.